# Inserting single values within cell range using button

Tags: vba, excel

I'm attempting to use VBA to insert a name into a small cell range (6 cells horizontally) with the following conditions in mind:

- Data should only be inserted in cells that are blank.
- Clicking the button a second time should remove the name if there are no empty cells within the range.
- Names should be inserted from left to right within the range.

I've managed to achieve some of this using the following code, but it is a little difficult since a cell is randomly selected within the range (sometimes have to click multiple times for the name to show up):

```
Sub button_onclick()

Dim rCells As Range
Set rCells = Range("N3:S3")

Dim rRandom As Long
    rRandom = Int(Rnd * rCells.Cells.Count) + 1

With rCells.Cells(rRandom)
    If IsEmpty(rCells.Cells(rRandom)) Then
        .Value = "Kent Allard"
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: if "names should be inserted from left to right", what is the purpose of picking a random cell?

Comment: That's just the best I could do as far as inserting the data. :(

Comment: Where the names are stored, or how they are generated?

Comment: @AlexBell I'm sorry. I don't quite understand the context of what you're asking.

Comment: Do you have only this name "Kent Allard" or there are other names as well? If so, how the VBA macro would know those names? Best regards,

Comment: @AlexBell There are 21 names in total that I have specifically called out in 21 separate VBA modules (one for each button). I imagine there is a better way of doing this, but I simply don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit unclear, so the answer is kind of generic: in order to achieve the goal as described, you can modify your Sub as shown below:

```
Sub button_onclick()
    Dim rCells As Range
    Set rCells = Range("N3:S3")

    Dim rRandom As Long
        rRandom = Int(Rnd * rCells.Cells.Count) + 1

    With rCells.Cells(rRandom)
        If IsEmpty(rCells.Cells(rRandom)) Then
            .Value = "Kent Allard"
        Else
            .Value = ""
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Pertinent to your modified requirements (Cells populated in sequential order instead of random, the last cell to clear if it's not empty), refer to the following code snippet:

```
Sub button_onclick()
    Dim rCells As Range
    Dim I As Integer, max As Integer

    Set rCells = Range("N3:S3")
    max = Range("S3").Column - Range("N3").Column + 1

    For I = 1 To max
        With rCells.Cells(I)
            If IsEmpty(rCells.Cells(I)) Then
                .Value = "Kent Allard"
                Exit For
            Else
                If I = max Then .Value = ""
            End If
        End With
    Next I
End Sub
```

Hope this may help.

Comment: Thanks for the response! While this does add the desired functionality of removing names when the button is clicked a second time, it is still attached to the random placement within the "N3:S3" range. I might not have been clear regarding this in my original post, but I'm trying to completely scrap the random functionality for sequential placement of the names from N3 to S3. The random placement is only there because I did not know how to achieve the desired result of left-to-right placement. This is one step closer though, so I really appreciate the response!

Comment: Please refer to the modified answer, and mark it accepted if satisfied with the solution. Should you have more questions, please post them separately. Good luck with your project. Best regards,

Comment: You, sir, have made my day. Thank you so much for your help, lending your skills, and your patience! Really appreciate it!

Comment: You are welcome! Good luck with your project. Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve. As far as I understand it, the following should achieve the task.

```
    Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim rCells As Range
    Dim rRandom As Long
    Dim intFilledCells As Integer

    Set rCells = Range("N3:S3")

    rRandom = Int(Rnd * 21) + 1

    ' You could achieve the placement of a random name by making a list
    ' of the 21 names (here it is supposed they are written in the cells A1:A21

   intFilledCells = WorksheetFunction.CountA(rCells)

    If intFilledCells <= 5 Then
        Range("N3").Offset(0, intFilledCells).Value = Range("A" & rRandom).Value
    Else
        Range("N3").Offset(0, intFilledCells - 1).Value = ""
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! While this is not exactly what I was looking for in the particular situation, it's a very nice technique that I will likely use elsewhere. Thank you again for contributing to this thread :)